# devise :password and :encrypted_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

in *devise* rails gem, what is the difference between these two?

I have seen the `:encrypted_password` field in the generated schema but not `:password` field.

Any explanations if these two are interconnected with each other?

Answer (score 4):

`Devise::Models::DatabaseAuthenticatable` has a setter for that:

```
def password=(new_password)
  @password = new_password
  self.encrypted_password = password_digest(@password) if @password.present?
end
```

So you should set the password as if there was a `password` field, devise will take care of encrypting it.

As @spickermann already pointed out - plain text password should never be stored anywhere and should filtered out from logs/error messages and so on, because this produces a huge security risk: the encrypted password leak is not totally harmless, but not dangerous that much.

Answer (score 2):

`password` is the plain text the user set as his password (and plain text password should never be stored anywhere). `encrypted_password` this the encrypted version of this password.

You might want to read [SecurePassword](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score 0):

`:password` is the password that a user sets through a form.

`:encrypted_password` is what is stored in your database and retrieved to create a user session.

Essentially, `:encrypted_password` is a hashed and salted version of `:password` that can be safely stored in your database. See [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/226002/why-should-passwords-be-encrypted-if-they-are-being-stored-in-a-secure-database) if you need more information on why you shouldn't store plain text passwords in your database.